# Array.includes() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, undefined

I am trying to take a user inputed word, check it against all the words in an array and then remove the words in the array that contain any of the same letters with something along the lines of:

```
var words = [
// words go here
]

for (let a = 0; a <= inputWord.length; a++) {
    for (let b = 0; b <= words.length; b++) {
        if (!words[b].includes(inputWord[a])) {
            words.splice(b, 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

The browser console is giving me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined." While testing I can print out `input[A]` fine, and I can print out `words[` random number of my choosing `]` fine, but when I try and print `words[b]` it's coming up undefined.

**Problem** 
 I'm unable to figure out why `words[b]` is undefined.

Comment: `splace` Spelling matters in programming. Check your console for errors.

Comment: An empty array will return undefined for your code you should use `b < words.length` if you're trying to loop over the array

Comment: Sorry about that! Fixed it in the question, but that's just me hurriedly writing the post. As far as I can tell everything seems to be spelled correctly in my actual code.

Comment: You shouldn't try to iterate from 0 to `<=` <arr>`.length` - stop *before* you reach the array's length. Even better, use `filter` instead, `for` loops are not so nice to work with

Comment: @Andrew thanks, I assumed I was doing something wrong in the for loop but didn't know what. Since I need to check the entire array is b < words.length + 1 the proper way to do this?

Comment: @ItaiYasur Just doing b < words.length is adequate. But you should sit down and rationalize it yourself and make sure you understand why. This is a very fundamental  programming concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indexing starts from 0.Run your loop from 0 - arr.length-1. The element at words[words.length] is undefined.

```
let words = [
// words go here
]

for (let a = 0; a < inputWord.length; a++) {
    for (let b = 0; b < words.length; b++) {
        if (!words[b].includes(inputWord[a])) {
            words.splice(b, 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Since the loop starts at 0 and array indexing also starts at 0, shouldn't there be an item at array[array.length]? As in array = [0, 1, 2], wouldn't array[array.length] here output 2?

Comment: @ItaiYasur array[array.length] will output undefined friend. And array[array.length-1] wll output 2. Here 0 - > is at index 0, 1- > is at index 1, 2 -> is at index 2. Length of array will be 3 as there are 3 elements in array. So if you do array[array.length], that will be equivalent to array[3] and no element is present at array[3] so it is undefined.